# How to get missForest output using rpy2 in Python?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm using rpy2 to run R package missforest in python. I know there is missingpy package in python which works similar to missforest package in R but i want to test other Imputation packages available in R  such as Amelia, Hmisc. Below is the code I created in Python, I was able to run missforest using rpy2 and get the output but unable to select the elements from the output. While running last line of below code, I'm getting invalid syntax error. I did search extensively and in the codes i got $ sign is being used with out problem but I'm not sure why the code below is giving error, how do I use $ sign using rpy2. Thanks.

```
######## Import and install relevant packages #########
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro
R = ro.r
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
######## Import the data and conver in to 'R' dataframe ########
data = pd.read_csv("path.csv")
data_imp = data[data.columns.difference(['id'])]
data_imp_r = pandas2ri.py2ri(data_imp)
####### run missForest ####
utils.install_packages(StrVector('missForest'))
survival=importr('missForest')
reslm=R.missForest(data_imp_r,maxiter = 10, ntree = 100, variablewise = True,decreasing = False, 
verbose = False)
######### from the output of missforest check OOB error ####
reslm$OOBerror
```

Comment: check out `.rx` and `.rx2` accessors in [the documentation](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/vector.html#extracting-r-style), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46014853/6646912 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29590454/6646912